# The requested project was not found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

When I tried to access my bucket on Google Cloud Storage with a Flask app I'm getting this error: google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 GET [https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET-NAME]?projection=noAcl](https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/%5BBUCKET-NAME%5D?projection=noAcl): The requested project was not found.
I tried from a Windows 10 machine with Google Cloud SDK installed and authorized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is now resolved.
Since I changed my project I had to changed it with the gcloud CLI but it didn't changed in the "application_default_credentials.json" file which is located in AppDatat/Roaming/gcloud. I only had to adjust the project ID there.

Comment: This helped me. The problem was I needed to renew the `application_default_credentials.json`. Thx

Answer (score 1):

make sure you set the `env variable` `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the path of the `key.json`

to check if it is set run `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`  if it output nothing that mean you need to set it by  `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="./path_to_your_json_file"`

these above commands apply only to `Unix/Linux/MacOS` systems

for `windows`:

`$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="KEY_PATH"`

for more [info](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#windows)